# How to display text from a pickled .txt file in a pygame window

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pickle

I have built a game that logs and saves the users score, using pickle, to a text file. When their lives are used up, they enter their name and their name and score are saved to a text file. Currently, if the "High Scores" section is selected on the main menu the high scores are simply printed in the python shell (or CMD if they're using that). I would like to create a separate window for just displaying the high scores. The window would simply display the scores and would refresh every time it is opened.

Currently I have the code to load the pickled file and create a new window. If I enter static text it works fine but when I try to display the text file contents I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LearnArabic\Program\Test1.py", line 22, in 
    textsurface = myfont.render(high_scores, False, (0, 0, 0))
TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from operator import itemgetter
import pickle

pygame.font.init()

high_scores = []

with open("C:\\LearnArabic\\HighScores\\HighScores.txt", 'rb') as f:
    high_scores = pickle.load(f)

#Background color 
background_color = (255,255,255)
(width, height) = (400, 500)

HighScoreScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('High Scores')
HighScoreScreen.fill(background_color)

#Displaying text on window
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
textsurface = myfont.render(high_scores, False, (0, 0, 0))
HighScoreScreen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))

pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Is there a different function from render that would allow me to display the results in a tabular form?

I'm relatively new to programming and am using python 3. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could blit the highscores onto another surface and then blit this surf onto the screen. To blit the highscore list, use a for loop and enumerate the list, so that you can multiply the y-offset by `i`. To toggle the highscore surface, you can just add a variable `highscores_visible = False` and then do `highscores_visible = not highscores_visible`, and in the main loop check `if highscores_visible: # blit the surf` (press 'h' to update and toggle the highscore table in the example below). Of course you need to make sure that the names and highscores fit onto the surface.

```
import pygame


pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

high_scores = [
    ('Carrie', 350),
    ('Arthur', 200),
    ('Doug', 100),
    ]

background_color = (255, 255, 255)

highscore_surface = pygame.Surface((300, 400))
highscore_surface.fill((90, 100, 120))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
highscores_visible = False

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_h:
                highscores_visible = not highscores_visible
                if highscores_visible:
                    highscore_surface.fill((90, 100, 120))
                    for i, (name, score) in enumerate(high_scores):
                        text = myfont.render('{} {}'.format(name, score), True, (0, 0, 0))
                        highscore_surface.blit(text, (50, 30*i+5))

    screen.fill(background_color)
    if highscores_visible:
        screen.blit(highscore_surface, (50, 50))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

---

Regarding the `TypeError`, you can't pass a list to `myfont.render` only a string or byte string, so you have to convert the list, e.g. `str(high_scores)`. However, if you just convert the `high_scores` list into a string before you pass it, pygame will render the whole list as one line. You need to use a for loop if you want several lines of text.

Comment: thanks for the help! I'm not sure how this resolves my issue though. Right now I can't display the info in the .txt file because of the TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes. Is there a way I can display or render the contents of my txt file?.

Comment: When I run your code I just get a blank window. Not even the high_scores that you set up are displayed. Am I missing something?

Comment: That was my issue! Thanks for pointing that out. I'm a bit new to programming so I'm not quite clear on my strings vs lists. I just put str(high_scores) in and now it works.

Comment: BTW, be careful with pickle. You should never unpickle files from untrusted sources, because they can contain malicious code. The json module is a safer alternative.

Comment: Could you make your comment about the TypeError an answer to your question? That's the real thing I was driving at (even if I conveyed it poorly).

Comment: So my next problem is displaying the information on multiple lines. If you're able, could you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46678084/8661593