# How can I display strings on multiple lines?

Tags: string, python-3.x, blit, pygame-surface

I am writing a "High Scores" table window for my pygame. Currently I am unpickling a file and then breaking the tuples apart so I can display the player name on the left and the score on the right. However in the current configuration, all of the player names are stacked ontop of eachother and the same with the scores. I need to figure out how to display each new player name and score combo on a new line. I'm still pretty new to python (working with version 3), any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
for x in high_scores:
    (Playername, score) = (x[0], x[1])
    print(Playername)
    Playername = Playername.rjust(25, " ")
    score = str(score)
    score = score.rjust(50, " ")
    megastring = megastring + Playername
    megastring = megastring + score

    Playersurface = myfont.render(str(Playername), True, (0, 0, 0))
    HighScoreScreen.blit(Playersurface,(0,0))
    scoresurface = myfont.render(str(score), True, (0, 0, 0))
    HighScoreScreen.blit(scoresurface,(0,0))
```

Thanks!

Comment: @skrx I know this code will work: 
    for i, (Playername, score) in enumerate(high_scores):
        text = myfont.render('{} {}'.format(Playername, score), True, (0, 0, 0))
        HighScoreScreen.blit(text, (50, 30*i+5))
    But it doesn't give me much room for formatting. Any thoughts?

Comment: Regards @JackDuane . If they were stacked together.. doesn't it mean that they were all have same position? ( `pos` ). What do you mean by not much room for formatting..?

Comment: Could you show us the desired output and how the names and score should be formatted? Have you experimented a bit with the code in my previous example? Also, please try to turn your code into an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run.

Comment: For the vertical offset you need to increase the y-coord of the `scoresurface` each iteration. The pythonic solution would be to `enumerate` the `high_scores` (as demonstrated in [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653550/6220679)), but you could also define a `y_pos` variable above the loop and then add some value to it each iteration, e.g. `y_pos += 30`.

Comment: @skrx, that was it! I defined an x_pos and y_pos and then added some value to it every iteration per your recommendation. I feel kinda silly now, it's so easy! Knowing that I can do it either way, is there a "right" or a "wrong" way to do it? Is enumerate better than defining a y_pos?

Comment: Both ways are okay, but as I said it's a bit more pythonic/idiomatic to enumerate the list.